# What's the space complexity of this code?

Tags: c++, big-o, space-complexity

```
int t;
cin >> t;
string *teacher;
teacher = new string[int(pow(t, 2))];
```

I believe the space complexity of the above code O(t^2), is that correct?

Comment: On an unrelated note: You almost *never* need pointers to standard containers or strings. If you ever need multiple containers or strings, use a *vector*, as in `std::vector<std::string> teacher(t * t);`

Comment: The real question here is: do you know what the `pow` function does?

Comment: @paddy Of course it returns t^2.

Comment: @Migo101 so, are you able to now answer your own question?  Is this homework?  Are you asking us to pre-grade your homework instead of just thinking about it and being confident that you answered to the best of your knowledge and ability?

Comment: Regarding your question: You say that you think the space-complexity is O(t^2). Why do you think that? What is your own thoughts and reasoning?

Comment: @paddy Confidence is hard to come by, especially for beginners. Getting external confirmation about ones thoughts and reasoning could help bolster the confidence.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because we have t^2 strings allocated in the memory, but I'm not sure about that.  I think complexity is O(t^2 * n) where n is the number of characters in each string.

Comment: It depends on how accurately you're required to describe the space complexity.  Firstly, the number of characters in these strings is zero.  Secondly, are you required to consider the size of the underlying data structure?  Normally with big-O, such things are not important because complexity is about how quickly the function grows with respect to its terms, so you generally disregard things like constant terms and scaling factors.

Comment: As the code is written, the space complexity is `O(t^2)`. However, if the strings are subsequently assigned in such a way that their size also depends on `t`, then that would affect the result.

Comment: Should also be noted that the space complexity here is bounded by the number of bits available to store an `int`, plus maybe some undefined behavior when you exceed that and it's truncated to a negative.

Comment: Please show how `string` string is defined. Is it `std::string`? Also, note that O(t^2) is only [pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `int(pow(t,2))` should be simply `t*t`.